# $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=l \implies f(x)$ is defined in a neighbourhood $c$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the following implication correct?

$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=l$ with $c,l \in \mathbb{R}\cup \big\{ +\infty,-\infty\big \} \implies f(x)$ is defined in a neighbourood of $c$ (besides the point $c$)

Thanks in advice

Comment: How would you evaluate the limit, otherwise?

Comment: Are you asked to prove this?

Comment: @jordan : Consider $x\ln x$.  It's not defined when $x=0$ but its limit as $x$ approaches $0$ exists. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It depends on context not given. Sometimes yes it would imply that by the definition.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: indeed, it depends on the context; anyway, for neiborhood $U$ of $x_0$, the domain of $f$ and $U$ has to have infinite points in their intersection; that's what I was meaning

Comment: @jordan : If you mean "infinitely many points" you should not write "infinite points". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael: ops :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb Q.$

Then $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in\Bbb Q,0<\left\lvert x-\sqrt2\right\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-1\bigr\rvert<\epsilon.$$ Hence, $\lim_{x\to\sqrt 2}f(x)=1,$ even though there are infinitely-many points of any neighborhood of $\sqrt2$ at which $f$ is undefined.

Comment: Thanks that was the kind of counterexample I was looking for